# Questions are no longer being accepted

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Right now Super User is no longer accepting questions from my account. Is there a way to override this?

Comment: See this help page: https://superuser.com/help/question-bans

Comment: I have seen that, but I don't know how to edit my questions in order to get my account reinstated.

Comment: Also see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/201411

Comment: Cody, welcome to Super User.  I see you've been in the SE network for a couple of months and here for a few weeks.  It looks like you haven't taken the site tour on any of the sites, and I suspect you haven't visited the Help section to see the guidance on asking questions.  The problem you're running into is viewing the site like a forum rather than like a knowledge base.  Your questions tend to be very general, at least as worded; often brainstorming or general knowledge type questions rather than focused problems that can be answered definitively from the information presented.  (cont'd)

Comment: Take the [quick tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and review the relevant guidance in the Help section (from the question mark icon at the top).  That will give you a better orientation to the kinds of questions that are a good fit.  It could be that the best venue to get the information you need is our general chat room, where you can have more of a discussion.  (cont'd)

Comment: Most of your questions that weren't well received have a lot of comments describing what's needed to improve them.  So start by editing the existing questions to address the issues raised in the comments and to add the requested detail.  That should influence the ban if it's enough to get some of the downvotes reversed.

Comment: @fixer1234 Comments should be for clarifications and asking for more details. You should really post that as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelFrank - Actually the this question should be closed as a duplicate of the existing question not answered again.

Comment: Crosspost of https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3060/52180

Comment: @Chenmunka, it would be cross-posting if Cody was aware that it is an automated system that applies throughout SE.  In this case, it's probably just an assumption that each site has its own policies. and he has created a similar problem on multiple sites.  It might be an incentive to read the help section.  :-)